# Returning user in hybrid environment, unable to migrate mailbox

Tags: email, active-directory, exchange

User returns after a couple of months, the AD profile was deactivated and the Microsoft 365 license was canceled. Doesnt matter that mails will be gone since its more than 30 days but what do I need to do to return email functionality?

What I have tried:
Activated user in AD.
Given the user a new 365 license in 365 admin center.
Enabled-mailbox for user and tried migrating the mailbox but get an error about user not being a mailbox.

In EAC on prem the mailbox shows up, in EAC online it doesn't. Admin center 365 shows user but no mailbox.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, Mailboxes in a soft-deleted state are recoverable for a period of 30 days before they are permanently removed from Office 365 and become unrecoverable.

Since you have said that you don't matter with missing mails, you may need to recreate a new user account on-premises with the same name as the deleted user, when the user syncs to Office 365 it will have a new object GUID. Step by step guidance for your reference: [Create Office 365 mailbox in Exchange hybrid](https://www.alitajran.com/create-office-365-mailbox-exchange-hybrid/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was that I did the migration too soon after enabling mailbox. Then when re-doing the migration the first migration blocked the second one. After removing the migration batch jobs and rerunning migration it worked.